# editbin and Visual Studio Express

Tags: visual-studio-express

I want to use editbin in some application, like
"editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE your-exe-file.exe"

but in my customer pc there is no visual studio...
Do you know if some Visual Studio Express versions comes with editbin?

Answer (score 2):

It should be included with [Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP).